# Which data structure to use for symbol table?

Tags: python

In python program, I am parsing a binary file to build the symbol table for it. Then, I want to associate addresses to symbols. For now my symbol table is a sorted List of `Symbol` objects which are made of an address, a length and a name and the symbol lookup naively iterates over the symbols. The lookup consists in finding which symbol contains a given address, in other words:

```
addr >= symbol.addr and addr < symbol.addr + symbol.length
```

Because the programs I am analyzing are getting very large, I am facing performances concerns, and looking for a more efficient (in terms of complexity) solution. I had a look at the `bisect` package, is it the right package to use in this case ? How would you implement that ?

Comment: `bisect` is just binary search, which probably isn't useful unless your symbol table is sorted. What kind of lookups are you doing in the symbol table? Can you just use a dictionary that maps the symbol name to the symbol object?

Comment: @Blender I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Blender no I can't because my lookup consists inf finding which symbol "contains" a given address as shown in the edited question

Answer (score 1):

You should probably take a look at `dict`.

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Comment: @I edited my question with more details. Can you please elaborate on your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could speed up the lookup by finding the closest address from the left with binary search:

```
import bisect

addr_to_sym = {sym.addr: sym for sym in symbols}
symbol_addrs = sorted(sym.addr for sym in symbols)

addr = bisect.bisect_left(symbol_addrs, 0xABCDEF)
sym = addr_to_sym[addr]

if addr <= 0xABCDEF <= addr + sym.length:
    # ...
```